# Local file links in RMarkdown not opening on macOS

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, r-markdown, knitr

Bit of a difficult one to replicate.

I have some RMarkdown files I want to knit to pdf. Inside these are links to some locally stored papers. In all the directory looks a little like

```
myfolder
---- markdowns
-------- mymarkdown.Rmd
---- papers
-------- JoeBloggsetal2019.pdf
```

so inside of `mymarkdown.Rmd` I have the equivalent of

```
[\textcolor{blue}{Joe Bloggs paper}](papers/JoeBloggsetal2019.pdf)
```

though Ive also tried

```
[Joe Bloggs paper](papers/JoeBloggsetal2019.pdf)
```

to no avail.

When knitted (to pdf) the mouseover picks up that its a link but nothing happens when I click.

Whats more confusing, is that all these files lived in an old parent folder with the same relative paths and upon knitting the links worked there.

Some vague ideas I've had:

- there are spaces in the actual pdf filenames?
- perhaps I was using a different pdf viewer before? (but none seem to work on macOS)
- obviously the paths go up a directory and then into the papers folder. Before, I was knitting from the parent and now maybe somehow its trying to knit from a different location? (though I have also tried "../papers/JoeBloggsetal2019.pdf")

I've also tried with a variety of different link types including https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/580 but without success.

For what it's worth, linking to urls is working fine

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine on Windows (you have to use `../` in order to go one level up in your directory:

```
[Joe Bloggs paper](../papers/JoeBloggsetal2019.pdf)
```

Here's a minimal reprex:

````
---
title: "test"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

[Joe Bloggs paper](../papers/JoeBloggsetal2019.pdf)
````

For generating the pdf I used tinytex.